# What the name of this book? Main character at relative's apartment, becomes leader of gargoyles

Tags: story-identification, books

All I can remember is the main character (not sure if male or female) is at a relative's apartment (I believe gramma) and the only part I can remember is finding gargoyles in the apartment and then she becomes the leader of gargoyles and the book ends.

Comment: Roughly when did you read this? Do you remember anything about the cover, or length of the book? Was it in English? Was it aimed at any particular age group?

Answer (score -1):

It's called The Gargoyle Queen I,m pretty sure. If not then it's Calling All Gargoyles.

Comment: I can't find a book by the name of "The Gargoyle Queen". Do you happen to know the author? Ditto with "Calling All Gargoyles".